# Open MPI - mpirun exits with error on simple program

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have recently installed OpenMPI on my computer and when I try to run a simple Hello World program, it exits with the next error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the program's source code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    printf("Hello\n");

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This is how I compile the program:

```
mpicc -o hello hello.c
```

and I execute it with

```
mpirun -np 2 hello
```

It throws no errors on compilation, and if I run `./hello`, it runs ok.

Excuse my english, any correction will be welcome.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same MPI distribution (OpenMPI, MPICH, MVAPICH) and version for compiling with `mpicc` and running the program `mpirun`. Your error could very well be caused my a mismatch in version and or distribution.

Comment: I've downloaded and installed the last stable version of OpenMPI. Before the install, I had no version of MPI installed

Comment: check the return values.

Comment: You mention that you used the last stable version but which version is that?

Comment: [This](https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/YefqHf8v/ompi-users-hello-world-runtime-error-primary-job-terminated-normally-but-1-process-returned-a-non) seems to be the same error. The answer below with `./` should work.

Answer (score 4):

you have to ./ the executable name
try this, mpirun -np 2 ./hello

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mpirun -x LD_PRELOAD=libmpi.so -np 2 hello
```

If it works, you probably have an issue with your OpenMPI installation. A simple workaround would be to define an alias. If ou use bash, add in *~/.bashrc*:

```
alias mpirun='mpirun -x LD_PRELOAD=libmpi.so'
```