# mpirun doesnt work and ask to change TMPDIR variable to /tmp

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I compiled the next code:

```
#include <mpi.h> 
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rank, size, len;
    char host[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I did it this way:

```
mpic++ -o test test.cpp
```

and then i tried to run the file:

```
mpirun -np 2 test
```

but the error occured:

PMIx has detected a temporary directory name that results
in a path that is too long for the Unix domain socket:

Temp dir: /var/folders/12/k2b2579s1yz2cfl8ppb1c6m80000gn/T/openmpi-sessions-501@MacBook-Air-Alexander-2_0/22793

Try setting your TMPDIR environmental variable to point to
something shorter in length

So I did this:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
```

Tried to run again: `mpirun -np 2 test`

But another error occured:

Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned

a non-zero exit code Per user-direction, the job has been aborted

### -------------------------------------------------------

mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

Process name: [[22798,1],0]

Exit code:    1

Tell me please, what should I do to run this code?

Comment: Your MPI installation is broken. How did you install it? What version do you use? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330511/open-mpi-mpirun-exits-with-error-on-simple-program Also read [ask] - your question title should be improved.

Comment: @Zulan: I have installed open-mpi via **brew install open-mpi**. My current version Open MPI v2.1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the initial error was already reported and this is considered as a feature.
using a shorted `TMPDIR` as you did is correct.

you might want to try adding

`orte_tmpdir_base = /tmp`

in your `openmpi-mca-params.conf` and see whether it fixes your problem
(so you will not have to set `TMPDIR` in every terminal)

about the second issue, you are very likely running `/usr/bin/test` instead of your test program, so you can simply

`mpirun -np 2 ./test`

or rename your test program into something that is not in your `PATH`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have compiled and run my code!

Comment: May I ask where I can find the 'openmpi-mca-params.conf' file?

Comment: It is in the `etc` sub directory of your install directory